# Error While Typesetting Quran Surah

Tags: arabic

I want to try to use `quran` package and following the example in the package documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{quran}
%%% for typesetting arabic text
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Amiri}
%%% for typesetting in Rigth−To−Left direction
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\setRTL % tell bidi to typeset the text in Rigth−To−Left direction
\textarabic{\quransurah*[95]}
\end{document}
```

When I tried on my computer I got error like this

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tes-quran.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/quran/quran.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/biditools.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/listofitems/listofitems.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/listofitems/listofitems.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/quran/qurantext-simple.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-arabic.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi.sty
****************************************************
* 
* bidi package (Bidirectional typesetting in
* plain TeX and LaTeX, using XeTeX engine)
* 
* Description: A convenient interface for
* typesetting bidirectional texts in plain TeX
* and LaTeX. The package includes adaptations
* for use with many other commonly-used packages.
* 
* Copyright (c) 2009--2019 Vafa Khalighi
* 2018-2020 bidi-tex GitHub Organisation
* 
* v35.11, 2020-01-29
* 
* License: LaTeX Project Public License, version
* 1.3c or higher (your choice)
* 
* Location on CTAN: /macros/xetex/latex/bidi
* 
* Issue tracker: https://github.com/bidi-tex/bidi/issues
* 
****************************************************
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/latex-xetex-bidi.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/footnote-xetex-bidi.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/article-xetex-bidi.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/loadingorder-xetex-bidi.de
f)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/arabicnumbers.sty
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/hijrical.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/cal-util.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amiri/Amiri.fontspec)
(./tes-quran.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \bbl@cs
           {beforestart}
?
```

But when I tried that on overleaf.com, nothing was wrong.

What is wrong with my texlive installation? What should I do in order to fix the error above?

Comment: I get no error with a fully updated TeX Live. Remove the `.aux` file and retry.

Comment: Magically, it worked! I don't know what happen. Thank you.